# Random Video via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a MySQL database in which i store the URL to 8 videos. What i want to do know is display them random in a slider. It's all working until now, besides that the video is not random but always the same, which means the video gets randomly picked from the database, but each time i refresh the page, it's 8 times video number 1, next refresh is 8 times number 6 etc.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("####", "####", "###", "clearchannel");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}                      

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT EmbedURL FROM Videos where location_id='2' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
$vid = $res->fetch_assoc();
?>  
                        <ul class="bxslider">
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                            <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: You're just pulling one result and echoing it over and over.

Comment: never post working server URL's on forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code with this new one:

1st. you r limiting your results to 3 urls from db, `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3"` change it to `8` if you want 8 different vidios,

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("####", "####", "###", "clearchannel");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
      }                      

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT EmbedURL FROM Videos where location_id='2' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");

 echo'<ul class="bxslider">';

while($url = $res->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<li><iframe src="'.$vid['EmbedURL'].'" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>'; 
}?>
                    </ul>
```

**EDIT:** a `}` was missing at the end.

Comment: I get something like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file index.php on line 159. Line 159 is empty tho, since the HTML is not that long o:

Comment: oh wait a minute it missing a `}` or `)` thats what causing the error

Comment: now it should work, or at least it wont show the error again

Comment: Yay! Working super fine! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

In each iframe you use the same variable `$vid['EmbedURL']` hence the result. If you want to get all the videos from your request, you need to use a while loop:

```
while($vid = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
  <li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
<?php
}
```

Also, I'm not sure using iframe is the best option. HTML5 supports different type of video very well.

Comment: What would you recommend? does my methos work with other than iframe? :o

Comment: It depends on how your css and code is structure, but you can try using the [video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). I usually try to avoid unsing iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put while on result:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<?php
while($vid = $res->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<li><iframe src="<?php echo $vid['EmbedURL']; ?>" frameborder="0" autoplay="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```